# How can i designate specific trace when using range slider in plotly?

Tags: plotly, rangeslider

I've known It's common way making figure object with `make_subplot` first,
fill it with `add_trace` second, and make range slider with 'update_layout' finally.

for example.

```
fig = make_subplot(rows=2, cols=1...)
fig.add_trace(go.CandleStick(...))  -----------------------------------------(first trace)
fig.add_trace(go.CandleStick(...))  -----------------------------------------(second trace)

fig.update_layout(xaxis==dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True)))
```

this rangeslider is usually applied to entire figure(all of first trace and second trace)
but, i want to know how to apply rangeslider to each trace separately

i could haven't this way in plotly document..

Comment: range sliders are applicable to an axis, from your pseudocode it's not clear you want the candlesticks to use different axes and how it would look.  you could set the second trace to use different x & y axes and then make rangefinder work on just one xaxis

Comment: I did this before with a for loop and processed every figure separately with its rangeslider, I didn't use make_subplot

Comment: For example I create a plot for the temperature for each country along with slider for 4 years. I plot every country with separate plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below shows multiple candlesticks in different subplots.  I recommend having ticker with **rangeslider** last so positioning works ok

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Initial data & get dataframe
start = dt.date(2022, 3, 1)
end = dt.date(2022, 3, 7)

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2,
    cols=1,
)

for i, ticker in enumerate(["MSFT", "AAPL"]):
    df = yf.download(ticker, start, end, progress=False, interval="1h")

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Candlestick(
            x=df.index,
            open=df["Open"],
            high=df["High"],
            low=df["Low"],
            close=df["Close"],
            name=ticker
        ),
        row=i + 1,
        col=1,
    )

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),  # hide hours from 4pm to 9:30am
    ]
)
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"rangeslider":{"visible":False}})
```

[image]